# Getting e-mail domain name (without TLD) on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, trim, charindex

I am trying to get only domain name from ***Email1*** column in **Users** table of my database.

```
UserId   Email1
  1      abc@gmail.com
  2      xyz@google.com
  3      xyz@abc.com
  4      abc@xyz.com
  5      123@stackoverflow.com
```

When I run this query:

```
SELECT LEFT( RIGHT(Email1, LEN(Email1)-CHARINDEX('@', Email1)),   
CHARINDEX('.', RIGHT(Email1, LEN(Email1)-CHARINDEX('@', Email1)))) 
as EmailNamePart FROM Users
```

I get the following:

```
gmail.
google.
abc.
xyz.
stackoverflow.
```

while the expected result should be:

```
gmail
google
abc
xyz
stackoverflow
```

Any clue what is wrong in my query?

Comment: What about email addresses with subdomains, or 2 extensions? I.e. `def@dba.stackexchange.com` or `xxx@msn.co.uk` or even `abc123@mail.yahoo.co.uk`? What values would you expect for those? Stripping the text up to and including the `@` is easy, but you can't assume that value after the last `.` is the extension.

Comment: Good question. In this case I would just remove from ```"@"``` to the first ```" . "``` after it. All I want is to take counts of these, to filter out cases like ```yahoo.se```, ```yahoo.in```, ```yahoo.com```, and stay with just ```yahoo```

Comment: careful what you use this for.  I could easily make an email address of gmail.example.com and your solution would output "gmail".  You can't make many assumptions about the incomplete domain name.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Grax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

-- if you only want to the first dot --

```
 select  SUBSTRING(Email1, CHARINDEX('@', Email1)+1,
 CHARINDEX('.', V.Email, CHARINDEX('@', Email1))-CHARINDEX('@', Email1)-1) as
 EmailNamePart FROM Users
```

-- if you want to the last dot --

```
select SUBSTRING(Email1, CHARINDEX('@', Email1)+1, 
(charindex('.', reverse(Email1) + '0') - len(Email1))*-1-(CHARINDEX('@', Email1)))
as EmailNamePart FROM Users
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment *"In this case I would just remove from "@" to the first " . ""* This would get you what you are after, but not sure it is what you *really* want:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('abc@gmail.com'),
                ('xyz@google.com'),
                ('xyz@abc.com'),
                ('abc@xyz.com'),
                ('123@stackoverflow.com'),
                ('def@dba.stackexchange.com'),
                ('xx@msn.co.uk'),
                ('abc123@mail.yahoo.co.uk'))V(Email))
SELECT LEFT(D.Domain,CI.Extension-1) AS SubDomain
FROM VTE V
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(STUFF(V.Email, 1,CHARINDEX('@',Email),'')))D(Domain)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('.',D.Domain)))CI(Extension);
```

Output:

```
SubDomain
-----------
gmail
google
abc
xyz
stackoverflow
dba
msn
mail
```

Comment: it works thanks. I have upvoted your answer but chose Kevin's answer better as it has no CTE.

Comment: @user102859 neither does mine; the CTE is for the sample data. I *had* to have *something* to test against. :)

Comment: You should test before you make such statements @Kevin. The above would return `'dba'` for that value; as the OP asked for.